# War depl Tomcat server JDBC& Mysql err--I copied my driver to Tomcat/lib and build war file by making my dependency as provided. Getting error still

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, tomcat, jdbc, war

```
-May-2019 18:29:47.938 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-24] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
The web application [SampleTest] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

16-May-2019 18:29:47.939 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-24] 

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [SampleTest] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it.
```

This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

I copied my driver to Tomcat/lib and build war file by making my dependency as provided. Getting error still

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks 

The web application [enimmPartner] created a ThreadLocal with key of 
type 
[org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler.LoggedExceptionHandlerThreadLocal] (value [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler$LoggedExceptionHandlerThreadLocal@11550dfc]) and a value of type [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler] (value 
[org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler@8864e34]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory 
leak.
```

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. You probably still have the driver included in your WAR as well. Remove it from the WAR.

Comment: What dependency I shall use in my pom.xml and respective application.yml config for jdbc connection, if I want to host my springboot application (war) on vps hosting?  I am using mysql 5 connector and latest mysql. Facing lot of issues. Any help will be highly appreciated.